# How to find DevExpress Grid Cell Active Editor element in WinAppDriver

Tags: devexpress, winappdriver, devexpress-gridcontrol

I am using WinApp Driver to test windows forms application that has DevExpress grid. When I click one of the cells it brings up active editor which contains more controls. I can identify active editor or controls within it using Recorder. However i cannot find this element using xpath provided by Recorder. How can I find active editor of dev express grid cell?